# Как экспортировать GPIO из device tree?

Tags: linux, kernel, gpio

Имеется Allwiner H3 процессор с загруженным на нём Linux. Каждый раз при загрузке железки делаю следующее

```sh
echo 203 >  /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio203/direction
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio203/value
```

дабы инициализировать ногу на вывод. Но это происходит уже в user space. А как бы экспортировать эту ногу из DTS?

Пробовал сделать так:

```dts
&pio {
    lock_ctrl {
        gpio-hog;
        gpios = <6 11 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; /* PG11 */
        output-high;
        line-name = "door_lock_control";
        status = "okay";
    };
};
```

но так не собирается даже. Пока экспортирую как LED и пользуюсь ногой через `gpio-led`, но "хочется" какой-то красоты...

Comment: А зачем? Тут видно общее непонимание кто есть кто. Идея такая, что у каждой линии должен быть свой provider (поставщик ресурса) и consumer (потребитель). Вот объясните вначале, кто у вас потребитель, и зачем все эти танцы с бубном.

Comment: По ходу пьесы будет управлять ногой софтина. Стандартного драйвера GPIO хватает с лихвой. Но вот состояние ноги по умолчанию при загрузке - `float`. т.к. вмешиваться в конструктив устройства уже не представляется возможным, а хочется иметь состояние ноги при загрузке output - `high`, то видится решение делать это софтово как можно раньше при загрузке. По сему хочется это сделать ещё в u-boot. Опять же, не хочется править исходный код самого "u-boot", а хотелось просто добавить экспорт со значением по умолчанию.

Comment: Да, вам нужен драйвер GPIO в U-Boot, и там же кодом или ещё как-то (не уверен насчёт DTS, потому что предложенные решения — всё ещё хаки). По-моему, это можно через команду `gpio` сделать. Так что через окружение и командную строку U-Boot мне видится самым чистым способом.

Comment: Если задавать начальное состояние портов в загрузчике, при переносе софта на другую железку, решение перестанет работать. Красивым я вижу решение собрать пакет, который прописывает это в загрузчик, а также ставит софт. Если это штучное изделие, конечно, можно без пакета.

Comment: @TotalPusher, так большинство систем работает. Откуда им начальное значение получить, если не из фирмвари? Вот загрузчик остаётся. То, о чём вы говорите, можно делать так же, как и в приведенном вопросе. Тогда непонятно, зачем вопрос.

Comment: Вот, похоже оно: https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2017-March/282865.html То есть включайте в U-Boot, и командой `gpio set $PIN; gpio output $PIN;` всё строится.

Answer (score 0):

По мне экпорт через led самый надежный в данном случае. Простой и надежный.

Вот ещё нашел пример DTS с тем похожем на то что нужно : https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/ec6293febc244d187e71a6e54f44920be679cde4/target/linux/ath79/dts/qca9531_glinet_gl-e750.dts#L38

Подвешанное состояние у ноги лучше решать апаратно: подтяните к + через резистор на исполнительном устройстве. Так ещё и решится проблема: когда плата компьютера отсоединена на исполнителе будет единичка.

Comment: Аппаратное решение или фирмварь, конечно хорошо, но LED — нет и нет.

Comment: @0andriy почему нет?

Comment: Даже не знаю, как это обернуть. Проблема в соответствии, точнее не соответсвии драйвера и железа. Не говоря уже о миллионе утилит, которые "случайно" могут начать использовать этот "светодиод". Разве это не очевидно?

Comment: какие? слуучайно? а ещё в dtb в драйвере led можно дать ему хорошее, человеко-читаемое имя

Comment: хотя вот нашел кой что..

Comment: Ага, какая-то кастомная штука под названием `gpio-export`. В апстриме нет такого.

Comment: @0andriy макрос какойто, надо dtsi глянуть откуда ноги у него, мне кажется переименованный led. В опенврт пока только в одном месте

Comment: https://devicetree.vger.kernel.narkive.com/hUDm3uhy/patch-gpio-add-export-with-name-from-dts иными словами в апстриме послали с такими идеями, и я полностью согласен с этим решением.

Comment: в апстриме много что зарубают, лет через пять реализуют эту же идею подругому

Comment: Ну пока что не случилось такого, а уже 8 лет прошло. И не случится, пока Linus Walleij  — мейнтенер подсистемы.